# Best model / approach to detect the number of standing bowling pins?

Tags: computer-vision

I want to build an ML model to detect the number of standing bowling pins, here is an example of an image from the dataset:

[image]

Do you think it's a hard task ? (considering that bowling pins are hidden by others, and that some half laid pins could be mistmatched with a standing pin).

I have looked at models like Faster R-CNN or YOLO, I mainly need an opinion about the difficulty of this task.

Thank you